# How to add Struts2 to a web application without web.xml?

Tags: spring, configuration, struts2, annotations, servlet-3.0

Can someone help me with a minimal project setup with Spring Boot and Struts2?
I have already create a Spring Boot application with a H2-database. I also added a `h2Configuration` class, so that I'm able to access the database with `localhost:8080/console`.

But how can I add Struts2 to my Application without `web.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

Without `web.xml` you can only write a Struts2 filter using servlet 3.0 or higher

```java
@WebFilter("/*")
public class Struts2Filter extends Struts2PrepareAndExecuteFilter {
}
```

The content could be empty, it's enough to add annotated filter without any inclusion in the `web.xml` file.

If you want to integrate Struts2 with Spring, then you should use a [plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html).

> Struts 2 provides a plugin that enables Spring to inject into the `ActionSupport` classes any dependent objects you've specified in the Spring configuration file. Consult Spring Plugin documentation for more information about how the plugin works.

Comment: Does not sprint boot support struts 2 integration ?

Comment: @MSach Spring Boot should use a plugin dependency.

Comment: as of verison 2.5.20   Struts2PrepareAndExecuteFilter -> StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: Thanks RomanC my comment is based on 'Struts2PrepareAndExecuteFilter' does not exist in struts2-core version 2.5.20 https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.5.20

Comment: @Nigel you should be aware of the date it is posted and the version of Struts at the moment.

Comment: Thanks romanC  we should always be trying to use the latest version for critical security / vulnerability patch(s). Its easy to miss the (2) in Struts2PrepareAndExecuteFilter and StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: @Nigel it is not so important the name of the filter an version of framework for this answer. The point is how to use servlet 3.0 annotation to start the framework.

Comment: Thanks RomanC you are correct, I was just trying to help if someone had issue with version 2.5.20 update, apologies for any confusion