# How to configure web.xml when using Struts 2?

Tags: java, xml, struts2, web.xml

I am New to Struts2. I don't understand that when i edit `web.xml`

```xml
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2></filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>  
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

i get an error : **Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

What should i do?

Comment: did you add `struts2-core` dependencies to your project ?

Comment: can you try with Tomcat 8.5 ? Early 8.0 versions had problems

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the class you wrote in the `<filter-class>` exists on the classpath, i.e. in the one of jars deployed with the application.

Read about [`web.xml`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/web-xml.html) used in Struts2 application. If you are using Struts 2.5.x the class should be

> ```xml
> <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
> ```

---

You might also want to know [How to add Struts2 filter without `web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416022/573032).