# HTTP Status 500-/index.jsp "/struts-tags" not found

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hi Can anyone help me out to resolve the error mentioned above.
I used a index.jsp file

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
       <form action="hello">
          <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
          <input type="text" name="name"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
       </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

After writing all the classes and xml files,I have run the classes by tomcat server but got an error as follows [image]

Can anyone help me out as I am new to Struts

Comment: Is your Struts 2 core jar is accessible/visible to tomcat. Make sure your Struts 2 core jar is available and configured properly in your application. this is jar related issue.

Comment: Have you added the struts2-core-.jar to the libraries of the project? If you have try to clean the project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613715/573032

Answer (score 0):

The taglib is included in struts-core.jar, and the container will discover it automatically.

for some reason, a taglib configuration is needed within web.xml, extract the TLD file from the struts-core.jar META-INF folder, and add a taglib element to the web.xml.

```
 <!-- ... -->
    </welcome-file-list>

    <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>/s</taglib-uri>
       <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This step should not be required on any even reasonably-recent servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Seems like you copied the libraries manually and directly into the folder WEB-INF/lib of the project and eclipse doesn't sense them, I suggest that you copy any necessary libraries into WEB-INF/lib only through eclipse. I had this issue previously and only a refresh of the project solved the problem.
2. add struts2-core.jar to the project
    download it [here](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/index.html).
   Select Project and right click, Click on the properties, Click on 
   libraries tab, Click on 'Add Jars', Add relevant jar for you.

Comment: I have added jars but it showing "missing" at the end of each jar in libraries section in eclipse IDE