# Not able to start Struts2 - Adding filter not working

Tags: struts2

I'm starting struts2. I've created a filter entry of struts2 in web.xml . When I start the server, its not starting. But when I remove the entry, its working. I've included commons-io, commons-logging, struts core, ognl, freemarker jars. Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
 <display-name>Struts2</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>

 <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### error console

```
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `when I remove the entry, its working` - without struts2

Comment: @RomanC, I wanted in struts2 only

Comment: If you use version 3.1 then you don't need to write it there. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31416022/573032